# Stripe Subscription Schedule Testing

Tags: stripe-payments

1:How can I test and trigger subscription scheduled.

```
$plan = Plan::create([
            'currency' => $currency,
            'interval' => 'day',
            'product' => $product,
            'amount' => $amount                
        ]);

        $schedule = SubscriptionSchedule::create([
            'customer' => $customer_id,
            'start_date' => 'now',
            'end_behavior' => 'release',                
            'phases' => [
                [
                    'plans' => [
                        [
                            'price' => $plan->id,
                            'quantity' => 1,
                        ],
                    ],
                    'iterations' => 3,
                    'collection_method'=> 'charge_automatically'
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        return $schedule;
```

So I create a subscription today, how I can test. Also when creating plan we can only specify billing frequency as either day, week, month or year.

Have already tried updating subscription Id with params

```
setting trial_end:  Few seconds from now
prorate: false
```

But this creates invoice for the same month. Also its creates another invoice with amt:0.(Dont know why it created).

2: Is this the same approach for testing subscription schedule.

Comment: Hey jones. What do you mean by "trigger subscription scheduled?" Do you mean `subscription_schedule.created`?

When you create a Price object in the API, you can specify the recurring.interval to set when it's daily, weekly, yearly etc. https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-recurring-interval

I don't know what you mean by the last question if it's the same for testing subscription schedule.

Can you say more about how you're trying to charge? What is your business model?

Comment: I am creating SubscriptionSchedule with plan for daily and iterations of 3 (Which I think means run the $plan->id for three days). I don't want to wait for 3 days to test. I have to test conditions like insuffucent balance, expire cards. How can I perform this type of testing without waiting for days/months.

Comment: The best way to test that is to set the billing_cycle_anchor to just a few minutes from "now" so that it forces the subscription to renew in a few min so you can test.

Admittedly, this isn't the best testing experience and we're working on improving it, but this is the best way to test today.

Answer (score 2):

I use Stripe's **[Test Clocks](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/test-clocks)**. Basically you simulate progress of time by setting a date and time in the future in order to make your subscriptions happen. Unfortunately you cannot use your existing Test `Subscriptions` and `Customers` but you have to create them just for the specific simulation.

Comment: In case your purchase flow creates a customer, you can get it to create a test clock automatically just before creating the customer object by calling the "Test clock" endpoint (https://stripe.com/docs/api/test_clocks/create). Then pass the ID of your created test clock in the `test_clock` attribute of the customer you create.